# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects (Inraster.Append)

Tags: python

Afternoon.

I've been thrown to the wolves so to speak in the python world; new job handed me scripts and wants me to tweak them to fit various data sets.

This is the code I modified:

```
#import arcpy module
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\\XXXXX_ET_data"

#Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

#Local variable:
Inpoints = "D:\\XXXXX_ET_data\\XXX_priority_locations_03112014Copy.shp"
fdata = "01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13"
fdata = fdata.split(",")

#initalizing the list
Inraster = []

#build list of inputs
for month in range (01, 13):
    for line in fdata:
        date = str(line+(month))
        Inraster1 = ["ma"+date+".modis.tif", date]
        Inraster.append(Inraster1)

#Process: Extract Multi Values to Points
arcpy.sa.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(Inpoints, Inraster, "NONE")
arcpy.gp.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints_sa(Inpoints, Inraster, "NONE")
```

I know my error is in the `line 21: date = str(line+(month))` so I was wondering how I would fix this; thanks in advance!

Comment: Should probably add that I'm using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`month` is an `int`. Convert it to `str` before concatenating it with `line`.

```
date = str(line+str(month))
```

This would get rid of the error. But I am not sure if it will fit in with the logic of the program, since I am not aware of the expected output.

Comment: The output is extracting values from MODIS data to the point; just updates the .shp file attribute table with the MODIS value for the given months.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `+` does both string concatenation and addition of `int`s and `float`s.

The line:

```
date = str(line+(month))
```

Is failing because the expression:

```
line+(month)
```

Attempts to use a string and an `int` as operands to `+`. If you want to do string concatenation, then use:

```
line+str(month)
```

This converts the integer `month` to its string representation before performing the string concatenation.

The complete line becomes:

```
date = line+str(month)
```

The “outer” `str()` is superfluous because the RHS is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

use format strings

```
date_str = "{0}{1}".format(line,month)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in fdata:
    date = str(line+(month))
    Inraster1 = ["ma"+date+".modis.tif", date]
    Inraster.append(Inraster1)
```

A more pythonic way of doing this would be:

```
ext = str(month) + ".modis.tif"
Inraster = ['{}{}{}'.format("ma", line, ext) for line in fdata]
```